# Newsletter howto

Tags: java, android, xml, database, newsletter

First thanks tor read this

I would like to create a newsletter thanks to my coded application under Android Studio: To be more clear, I would like to create a list of email address thanks to a form on my application. I have already created the form but I do not know how to send email addresses to a database (or other, the database being the only option that comes to mind)
Here is my form:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.streetworkoutarrasFR.view.NewsletterActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_newsletter">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="214dp"
        android:layout_height="191dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="95dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="102dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="102dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/swa"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="87dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nltest"
        android:layout_width="362dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="NEWSLETTER"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nlbio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nltest"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="389dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:text="Souscrivez à notre newsletter gratuite pour voir nos derniers contenus et avoir de bons conseils pour progresser ainsi que du contenu exclusif!"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textStyle="italic" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="245dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nlbio"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Votre adresse e-mail..." />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-45dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText3"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Subscribe" />







</RelativeLayout>
``
```

Comment: start from the official docs: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite

Comment: Ok thanks I'm gonna read that, but i read that it was just local, is that true or can we recuperate the values?

Comment: use firebase if you want remote